# Descarga de archivo .CSV en firefox no funciona correctamente con aplicacion web

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una aplicación web usando aspx y con código C#. Estoy usando `HttpResponse` para poder descargar el resultado en un archivo CSV.

Cuando uso Chrome descarga sin problemas con la extensión .csv. El problema se encuentra cuando uso FireFox, el archivo que descarga es file (sin extensión).

Aquí esta mi parte de codigo usando `HttpResponse`

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ContentType = "text/csv";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + outCsvFile + ";");
response.TransmitFile(outCsvFile);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

¿Cual podría ser el problema?

Comment: cual es el filename que te llega ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asegúrate que el nombre del archivo posea la extensión requerida. Esto es, el nombre que indicas en la cabecera `"filename="` debe tener la extensión `.csv` en él.

Ejemplo:

```
string nombre = outCsvFile + ".csv";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombre + ";");
```

Quizás Chrome es bondadoso y está agregando esa extensión tras validar el content-type de tipo "text/csv".

Comment: Hola, el archivo outCsvFile contiene mas arriba la extension .csv. tendria que agregarle manualmente igual la extension .csv?

Comment: Cuando tienes este código: `response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + outCsvFile + ";");` la variable `outCsvFile` debe ser algo como `"nombre.csv"`. Si no lo tiene presente, el navegador cliente puede o no puede agregar la extensión por ti. Si quieres estar seguro, coloca la extensión tú mismo.

Comment: si me resulto. Agregando la extension al final resulto sin problemas. muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: De nada, para atenderte

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo problema para descargar un .PDF en Firefox
Dejo este código de ejemplo, quizá pueda ayudar a alguien más. Pueden usar la barra invertida "\" al principio y al final del nombre del archivo.

```
Ressponse.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "\"" + FileName + "\"");  
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile("~/Logs/temp/" + FileName);
```